# Invisible dynamic methods for devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a problem with methods like current_manager, current_receptionist etc.

There are invisible, without methods for client. It is caused by routing. I placed devise_for all types of people(without client) in namespace backend. When I move above this namespace all methods are available. However I want this declaration:

```
devise_for :receptionists, :managers...
```

have in backend namespace.

How should I modify my code to allow correct visibility methods?

Dynamic methods in **controllers/backend_controller.rb**:

```
class BackendController < ApplicationController
      %w(Manager Receptionist Lifeguard Trainer).each do |k|
        define_method "current_#{k.underscore}" do
          current_person if current_person.is_a?(k.constantize)
        end

        define_method "authenticate_#{k.underscore}!" do |_opts = {}|
          send("current_#{k.underscore}") || not_authorized
        end

        define_method "#{k.underscore}_signed_in?" do
          !send("current_#{k.underscore}").nil?
        end
      end
end
```

Routing:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :people, controllers: { sessions: 'devise/sessions' },
                      skip: [:registrations]
  devise_for :clients, skip: :sessions
  namespace :backend do
    devise_for :receptionists, :managers, :lifeguards, :trainers,
               skip: :sessions, controllers: { registrations: 'devise/registrations' }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem, by add methods to **application_helper** (in backend_controller still keep).